# assign value from one vector to a group based on another vector in R

Tags: r

I have 2 vectors:

```
v1 = c(4, 8, 13)
v2 = 1:20
```

I want to classify each element in `v2` to a specific group depending on the element comparison. In this example, values 1:4 from v2 will be classed to group1, values 5:8 to group2, values 9:13 to group3, and values 14:20 to group4.

I would like to have a final df like

[image]

Any suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `%in%` with `cumsum` to create the index and `paste` 'group'

```
data.frame(ls2 = v2, group = paste0("group", cumsum(v2 %in% (v1 + 1)) + 1))
```

-output

```
 ls2  group
1    1 group1
2    2 group1
3    3 group1
4    4 group1
5    5 group2
6    6 group2
7    7 group2
8    8 group2
9    9 group3
10  10 group3
11  11 group3
12  12 group3
13  13 group3
14  14 group4
15  15 group4
16  16 group4
17  17 group4
18  18 group4
19  19 group4
20  20 group4
```

Answer (score 1):

There are likely more universal/elegant solutions, but to recreate the desired dataset given the example, you could try:

```
group <- case_when(v2 <= v1[1] ~ "group1",
                   v2 %in% (v1[1]+1):v1[2] ~"group2",
                   v2 %in% (v1[2]+1):v1[3] ~"group3",
                   v2 > v1[3] ~"group4"
)

cbind(v2, group)
# v2   group   
# [1,] "1"  "group1"
# [2,] "2"  "group1"
# [3,] "3"  "group1"
# [4,] "4"  "group1"
# [5,] "5"  "group2"
# [6,] "6"  "group2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use `findInterval`?

```
data.frame(
  v2,
  group = paste0("group", findInterval(v2, v1, left.open = T) + 1)
)
```

**Output**

```
   v2  group
1   1 group1
2   2 group1
3   3 group1
4   4 group1
5   5 group2
6   6 group2
7   7 group2
8   8 group2
9   9 group3
10 10 group3
11 11 group3
12 12 group3
13 13 group3
14 14 group4
15 15 group4
16 16 group4
17 17 group4
18 18 group4
19 19 group4
20 20 group4
```

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward approach is:

```
id = seq_len(length(v1) + 1)
n = diff(c(0, v1, length(v2)))

rep(id, n)
#[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
v1 = c(4, 8, 13)
v2 = 1:20

data.frame(v2, groups = cut(v2, breaks = c(0,v1,20),
           labels = paste0("group", 1:(1+length(v1)))))

#>    v2 groups
#> 1   1 group1
#> 2   2 group1
#> 3   3 group1
#> 4   4 group1
#> 5   5 group2
#> 6   6 group2
#> 7   7 group2
#> 8   8 group2
#> 9   9 group3
#> 10 10 group3
#> 11 11 group3
#> 12 12 group3
#> 13 13 group3
#> 14 14 group4
#> 15 15 group4
#> 16 16 group4
#> 17 17 group4
#> 18 18 group4
#> 19 19 group4
#> 20 20 group4
```